# How to wire 1 humbucker to a 6 position rotary switch without tone and volume pots?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, pick-ups, electronics, wiring

Any help would be useful diagrams?

Comment: Well, what do you want that 6-pos switch to do?

Comment: to just be able to switch between all possible wiring of the pickup, like splitting it parrell etc. all possible ways with the rotary.

Comment: Both in phase, both out of phase, one on, other on seem to be the 4 options.

Comment: Sounds great to me, any diagrams?

Comment: There actually are six options: serial in phase, serial out of phase, parallel in phase, parallel out of phase, coil A alone, coil B alone. But it's probably not possible to get access to all of these. At any rate we'll need to know what this switch is you're talking about – there are plently of different models.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Allparts-EP-0920-000-6-position-Rotary-Switch/dp/B002HFKVYQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1519928880&sr=8-1&keywords=6+position+rotary+switch+guitar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a full 4-pole switch, it's easy to figure out a routing – just assign each of the wires coming out of the PU a pole.

Then for each setting of the knob, you can freely decide where the signal should go. You'll definitely want the standard serial wiring (i.e. opposite coil polarities in series, so the opposite magnets will bring the signals in phase)

[image: The ordinary serial circuit]

and probably also the brighter-sounding parallel variant with the same phase

[image: Humbucker in (humbucking) parallel mode]

Extend to other wirings as you see fit. Single-coil splitouts are the obvious third choice, followed by out-of phase arrangements. All of these are frankly much less useful though in practice – an out-of-phase humbucker sounds *extremely* weak/thin, which is particularly bad since, like a SC tap out, it doesn't actually humbuck anymore. So, a more practical alternative migh be to offer a whole bunch of variations on the serial circuit, with different capacitors to short out the high frequencies from one of the coils.

[image: pseudo-single-coil circuits without hum]

All of these woult be mostly hum-free, but in the crucial midrange the capacitor-shortened coil won't contribute much so it'll actually sound more like a single coil.